# regex in file over several lines replacing

Tags: javascript, regex, phpstorm

I have a regex like this:

```
/ requires: \[.*("Instance.model.*?").*\] /gs
```

And I have data like this:

```
requires: [
    "Instance.model.a",
    "Instance.model.b",
    "Instance.model.c",
    "Other.mode.test",
    "Instance.model.d"
],

"Instance.model.e"
```

I want to delete all `"Instance.model.?",` in this file inside the requires, but the given regex only returns the last entry (d).
How can I get this working in PhpStorm?

Comment: It is because of the quantifers `.*` wich will match until the end first, and will then backtrack to capture the last value only in the group. You could get the whole match first to make sure you have the right part, and then replace the values inside that match.

Comment: See for example https://tio.run/##dY7LDoIwEEX3/YqmGx7BsocY1q78AIqhlgliSsG2GP@@NvjAEJnluXNu7pXfuRG6G@1ODQ04h/2JQRmLNbTwwHucarhNnQaTYVYyReOCHHzOlQDae0fSmDDFqrTtTY4W31jt7Xqxyzlcy5wkf/l5g4sPP9oL6BlSC8ZuvDcEVQlCawyk/t3q903S@rl@NNUwSi4gTL8Se1nliTDNVBWTsMgSpqIibRMcBNFSNUigcmjDd2OUO/cE

Comment: Using chrome or nodejs with chrome v8 you could also use lookarounds with a quantifier in the lookbehind https://regex101.com/r/sOB0Mj/1

Comment: I am trying to replace these in PhpStorm.

Comment: You could try `(?<=^requires: \[[^\[\]]*)"Instance\.model\.[a-z]",?\r?\n` https://regex101.com/r/xkGkqi/1 and replace with an empty string, or a bit more strict version also checking for the closing `]` https://regex101.com/r/XNX82L/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird both are not working inside PhpStorm

Comment: I am not sure what the regex engine is, if it is Java you could try `(?<=^requires: \[[^\[\]]{0,1000})"Instance\.model\.[a-z]",?\r?\n`

Comment: @Thefourthbird no, still not working. PhpStorm is the same as IntelliJ

Comment: I have it working in my Intellij, Maybe I have a plugin installed I am not aware of. Just to be sure, you have clicked the **.*** regex mark right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks a lot. The final search string is: `(?<=^ {0,8}requires: \[[^\[\]]{0,1000})"Instance.model.[a-zA-Z]*",?\r?\n?`

Comment: @Thefourthbird if you add your answer I can mark it as answer

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I have added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If supported, one option is to use an infinite quantifier in the lookbehind `*` or use a finite one `{0,1000}` when using Java for example.

```
(?<=^requires: \[[^\[\]]{0,1000})"Instance\.model\.[a-z]",?\r?\n
```

*Explanation*

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `^requires: \[` Match requires from the start of the string followed by space
  - `[^\[\]]{0,1000}` Match 0 - 1000 times (this value you can change accordingly) any char except square brackets
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `Instance\.model\.` Match `Instance.model.`
- `[a-z]",?\r?\n` Match a char a-z, optional comma and a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LMA954/1)

From the comments, the final pattern that worked for you (with the escaped dots)

```
(?<=^ {0,8}requires: \[[^\[\]]{0,1000})"Instance\.model\.[a-zA-Z]*",?\r?\n?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4D87XM/1)